# Match only Upper and Lowercase letters with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am given a string (name) and it is supposed to check for the following:

- between 2 and 30 characters
- name can only contain alphabets and spaces
- First character of each work should be upper case
- Each word separated by space
- Name cannot start or end with space
- Special characters not allowed

here is my regex string: `"[[[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]*[\\s]?+]{2,30}[^\\s]"`

"Roger Federer" should be valid, and this says it is
"Roger federer" should NOT be valid, but mine says it is
"Roger Federer $" should NOT be valid, but mine says it is

I'm curious if I'm enforcing these wrong, I am very new to regex

Comment: `matches("(?=.{2,30}$)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*(?:\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)*")`

Comment: why does it have to be all in a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
^(?=.{2,30}$)\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*$
```

If you want to allow one *or more* whitespaces between words, add `+` after `\s`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Emrg0h/1).

In Java, the regex declaration will look like

```java
s.matches("(?=.{2,30}$)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*(?:\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)*")
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - (implicit in `matches`) - start of string
- `(?=.{2,30}$)` - two to thirty chars required in the whole string
- `\p{Lu}\p{L}*` - an uppercase letter followed with zero or more letters
- `(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*` - zero or more occurrences of a whitespace, then an uppercase letter and then zero or more letters
- `$` - (implicit in `matches`) - end of string.

If you want to only match ASCII letters, replace `\p{Lu}` with `[A-Z]` and `\p{L}` with `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: yup that'll do it